# Apache POI serialization issue in spring batch

Tags: apache-poi, spring-batch

I am using spring batch(3.0.3) and apache poi to generate report. It prepares the excel file properly but at the end of job, it throws exceptions like this

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1133)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize a `XSSFCell`?

Comment: I am not trying to serialize, it is spring batch framework which is trying to store data in their db(batch tables) in case of restart needed.